# Update Lowest ID Only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, update

We have two tables that are joined on Social Security #'s, but for the sake of this example, I have altered it to join on name only.  One table holds each individual sale, and the other table holds the employee's annual salary.  I need to compile this data into one table, and only update **ONE** row from the individual sale table with the annual salary.  How can I update the smallest saleid for each employee?

Below is sample DDL:

```
Declare @Helper Table (empname varchar(50), saleid int, sal float)

Declare @Helper1 Table (empname varchar(50), sal float)

Insert Into @Helper (empname, saleid) Values
('Number One', 818181), 
('Number One', 19213), 
('Number One', 919131),
('Number One', 131311313)
,('Number Two', 131313), 
('Number Two', 9823), 
('Number Two', 24)

Insert Into @Helper1 (empname, sal) Values
('Number One', 44000.00), ('Number Two', 55000.00)
```

This is my desired output:

```
empname     saleid  sal
Number One  19213   44000
Number One  818181  
Number One  919131  
Number One  131311313   
Number Two  24      55000
Number Two  9823    
Number Two  131313
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try something like:

```
update h
set sal = t.sal
from @Helper h
join (
    select h.empname, h.saleid, h1.sal, row_number() over(partition by  h.empname order by h.saleId ) as n
    from @Helper h
    join @Helper1 h1 on h.empname = h1.empname
    ) t on h.empname = t.empname and h.saleid = t.saleid
where n = 1
```

(assuming the primary key of `@Helper` in on `empname` + `saleid`)

Comment: That's exactly what I was after, thank you,  (And yes, safe assumption!)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @irimias' answer but without the extra join:

```
with upd_helper as
  ( select h.sal, 
           new_sal = h1.sal, 
           rn = row_number() over(partition by h.empname order by h.saleId)
    from @Helper as h
      join @Helper1 as h1 
      on h.empname = h1.empname
  )
update upd_helper
set sal = new_sal
where rn = 1 ;
```

Tested at [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/IKQEK27975)